# c++ function not working

Tags: c++, function

Here is my function definition to calculate a winner in an auction depending on the relationships between the two bids. It is not bringing out the correct "winningBid" and often it skips to printErrorMessage 4 even when those conditions have not been met.

```
void calcWinner(string bidder1, string bidder2, string lotName, 
                double bid1, double bid2, double reservePrice)
{
    double winningBid;
    string winningBidder;
    if (bid2<reservePrice && bid1<reservePrice) 
        printErrorMessage(4);
    else if (bid2>=reservePrice && bid1>=reservePrice)
    {
        if (bid2<bid1){
            winningBid=bid2+.50;
            winningBidder=bidder1;}
        else if (bid2>=bid1 && bid2<(bid1+.50)){
            winningBidder=bidder1;
            winningBid=bid1;}
        else if (bid2>(bid1+.50)){
            winningBidder=bidder2;
            winningBid=(bid1+.50);}
    }
    else if (bid2>reservePrice && bid1>=reservePrice){
        winningBidder=bidder1;
        winningBid=reservePrice;}
    else if (bid2>=reservePrice && bid1<reservePrice){
        winningBidder=bidder2;
        winningBid=bid2;}
    printWinner(winningBidder, lotName, winningBid);
}
```

Comment: -1 Your code is hard to read. Indent the nested `if`s better. Also, please choose more suggestive titles for your questions.

Comment: When posting questions like this, it's helpful to show the actual inputs to your function where you observed the incorrect behaviour. This is much more considerate than "here's my code, it doesn't work, tell me why".

Answer (score 3):

You should really write down your rules in plain English rather than code (assuming you haven't yet), then try to simplify them. That seems like an awfully large amount of code for a situation that basically boils down to (I think):

```
void calcWinner (string bidder1, string bidder2, string lotName,
                 double bid1, double bid2, double reservePrice)
{
    // Error if both less than reserve.

    if ((bid2 < reservePrice) && (bid1 < reservePrice) ) {
        printErrorMessage (4);
        return;
    }

    // If only ONE less than reserve, other one wins.

    if (bid1 < reservePrice) {
        printWinner (bidder2, lotName, bid2);
        return;
    }

    if (bid2 < reservePrice) {
        printWinner (bidder1, lotName, bid1);
        return;
    }

    // Both at least reserve at this point, bidder1 wins if higher bid, but
    // only pays bid2 + 50c.

    if (bid1 >= bid2) {
        printWinner (bidder1, lotName, bid2 + 0.5);
        return;
    }

    // Bidder1 also wins if bidder2 didn't beat them by 50c or more, but
    // only pays what they bid.

    if (bid2 < bid1 + 0.5) {
        printWinner (bidder1, lotName, bid1);
        return;
    }

    // Otherwise, bidder2 wins, pays 50c more than bid1.

    printWinner (bidder2, lotName, bid1 + 0.5);
}
```

*That's* how I would structure code like this, with a clearly defined set of rules in order of decreasing precedence. That way, it's an easy mapping between your English rules and your code.

---

For what it's worth, I think you had at least two problems in your original code:

- First, `else if (bid2>reservePrice && bid1>=reservePrice){` should have been checking for `bid2` being *below* the reserve (so that `bid1` wins by default).
- Second, `else if (bid2>=bid1 && bid2<(bid1+.50)){` and `else if (bid2>(bid1+.50)){` do *not* take into account the possibility that `bid2` could be *exactly* equal to `bid1 + 0.5`. That would cause `winningBid/winningBidder` to be left at "random" values, meaning your output could be anything.

But I'd seriously not even consider going back to fix them. Far better in my opinion to implement the precedent-based rules approach I gave in my code. While the rules you have may not be an exact match for what I've provided, it's far easier to figure out what changes you should make (as opposed to your original code).

The comments I have in the code are basically the English rule set and the approach you take should be similar.

Comment: @pwned, so is the `main` function, and the design specifications, and the requirements traceability matrix. If I was being paid as per my normal job, you'd get them all :-) As it is, I like to leave _some_ work for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

On the second last `else if` I suppose you meant `bid2<reservePrice`, not `bid2>reservePrice`.

Answer (score 0):

- You don't handle the case where `bid2<reservePrice && bid1>=reservePrice` because of a typo in your comparison.
- the logic inside the `bid2>=reservePrice && bid1>=reservePrice` case is fishy (for instance if `bid2<bid1`, the `winningBid` value maybe larger than `bid1`)